# loc method to update the values in an existing column consistency?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following toy example of a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'b':['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'ee']})
```

And here is what I am doing:

```
df.loc[df.a < 3, 'a'] = df.a * 0.95
```

Please advise how pandas "knows" to adjust `df.a` to be only the first 2 rows (the output will be the first 2 rows of `a` column (0.95, 1.90)?

```
       a     b
0   0.95    aa
1   1.90    bb
2   3.00    cc
3   4.00    dd
4   5.00    ee
```

Comment: df.a < 3 this return Boolean, tell panda only do the row return True

Comment: What @BENY said, the `df.a < 3` returns a series of booleans that acts as mask to select only the target rows.

Comment: I must admit I do not have enough knowledge of how it works under the hood if that is what you are asking for. Anyhow, [this explanation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DpyhdO4aM04&ab_channel=PyData) could be a good starting point. The instants 14:55 and 32:04 might be the ones you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the condition `df.a < 3`, Pandas will effectively take note of the indices in the dataframe for which the condition holds true. Therefore, when it applies the transformation: `df.a * 0.95`, it knows to only apply it to the relevant indices.

Comment: It's somewhere in it's settings? Python interpreter level? What is the mechanism behind the scenes?

Comment: That's too low level for me I'm afraid! If what you want is to return only two rows, then it is better to filter the dataframe first and create a new dataframe object in doing so. Then apply the transformation